# How to host ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in a .NET 6 WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Here's what I did in .NET 5, copying the `Startup.cs` and `appsettings.json` of the Web API project.

```
using System.Windows;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
             base.OnStartup(e);
   
             Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                      {
                           webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                      })
                 .Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But in .NET 6, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why are you wanting to run a HTTP web-server in-proc? What problems does it solve? If you just want IPC then there are _much better_ alternatives that don't involve going through loopback connections.

Comment: You can do exactly the same in .NET 6. Minimal hosting model is not required you can always switch to the generic one.